# jquery: prevent div from hiding if mouse event occurred on another div

Tags: jquery, css

i have this simple example here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/pTyvc/1/
i don't want the sub_menu div to slideUp if mouse is over it any help ? thanks

Comment: It doesn't collapse for me. Perhaps your browser doesn't like you.

Comment: he means if you move to the blue block. it does it for me too.

Comment: Oops sorry, it doesn't like me either :)

Comment: Its because of the mouseleave event.

Comment: ya it's because the mouseleave so how to keep it showing till the sub_menu mouseleave

Comment: well I tried in the fiddle to remove the mouseout but then it never became hidden unless you hovered another item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `mouseover` because `mouseenter` is not fired when you move from a child element to the parent element.

Also, when you mouseover a sub menu, you'll have to `.stop()` the animation to keep it from sliding up. The same applies for moving the mouse from the sub menu to the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/pTyvc/25/

```
$(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected")
        .children().stop().slideDown(500);
});

$(".menu_item").mouseout(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass("selected")
        .children(".sub_menu").slideUp(500);
});

$(".sub_menu").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop();
});
```

Comment: @Yasser: I see it actually starts acting weird if you move the mouseover the sub menu when it's sliding down. This seems a bit complicated.

Comment: Add '.animate({height:'100px'});' after 'stop()' in order the div will continue to slide down to the full height

Comment: @Hadas: Thanks, though it makes for some delay when hovering now.

Comment: @pimvdb Sure,it stop and only then animate